BLDC HFI Observations
I came here in the hope someone guides me along the steep path of High Frequency Injection.
As a first Test, I connected my motor to a ~2kHz 33% Duty Square Wave, with one Phase switching to positive, and the other two to negative. The Driver is l6234. the Signal goes to the 1,2,3 Enable Lines, and the Inputs 1, 2, 3 are high, low, low. I then scoped the original Signal, as well as the Output Voltage and Current of that one phase.
I examined a rise of about 100mV in Peak Voltage and Current, when changing the angle of the rotor to a position between the stable points. The Motor is an 8 pole rated at 24V / 50W.
I'd as a first step appreciate critical input concerning my setup and methodology.
The final goal is to get smooth slow speed operation (60 RPM) under steady load condition.
Maybe there is a much more simple way to achieve this?
Openloop, was jerky so far.
For > 250 RPM I am satisifed with the feedback of the motors' Hall-Sensors, and
a sythesized 3rd Harmonic injected Sinusoidal Waveform, timed, based on the measured Velcovity in between the Hall Events as a guidance. I do beforehand calibrate the Hall Event Offsets in Software at CW + CCW for all 24 Events.
Please see the Plots of my HFI.
Legend: blue-F-Gen, yellow-Voltage, pink-current
1.Plot: rotor aligned to magnetic field
2.Plot: rotor in between stable positions.




I am satisifed with the feedback of the motors' Hall-Sensors, and a sythesized 3rd Harmonic injected Sinusoidal Waveform, timed, based on the measured Velcovity in between the Hall Events as a guidance.

You only need the Hall sensors for initial commutation. Once the rotor is turning, the usual self-sensing feedback will help you get a decent estimate of the rotor position and velocity. Depending on how well it's designed, it can work to fairly low speeds. Instead of a self-sensing setup you may wish to use a small magnet on the shaft, and a magnetic angular position sensor. It will work down to 0 RPM, and no need for separate Hall sensors then.
